# OpenCV in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, opencv

Following is my program:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image = imread("/Users/hanxu/Pictures/me.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Image load failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Image_Colored");
    imshow("Image_Colored", image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

An error occurred:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h:196:14: Use of undeclared identifier 'use_speed_'
```

The code there is :

```
#if USE_UNORDERED_MAP
    if (!use_speed_) buckets_space_.rehash((buckets_space_.size() + dataset.rows) * 1.2);
#endif
```

Initially, Xcode does not support unordered_map, I changed "C++ Standard Library" in building setting to "with C++11 support".

Comment: I got the same error too, have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing this line in lsh_table.h

```
if (!use_speed_) buckets_space_.rehash((buckets_space_.size() + dataset.rows) * 1.2);
```

to

```
buckets_space_.rehash((buckets_space_.size() + dataset.rows) * 1.2);
```

You can find more info on https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/pull/51/files